# Android Studio - access drawable by string in a non activity?

Tags: java, android

How can I access drawable by string in a non activity without getting any parameters like Context?

Comment: Pretty sure you need a Context to access any resources. You can pass your activity context as a parameter to whereever you need that drawable.

Comment: Why would you not want to pass `context` as a parameter? If you have any specific reasons then do put them in your question as that can help us answer better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 
ContextCompat.getDrawable 
or 
Resources.getSystem().getDrawable() - note this is deprecated